# django raw_id_field javascript callback

Tags: django, django-admin

Consider this example:

**models.py**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    something = models.ForeignKey(Something)


class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option)
```

**admin.py**

```
class BarInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Bar

    raw_id_fields = ('option',)


class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ('something',)
```

So when I create a fresh `Foo object`, no `BarInlines` have been defined yet.

Without saving the `Foo object` first I would like to limit the BarInline option field's options by adding a parameter (e.g. `&option__id=<something>`) to the javascript trigger. But how do I hook into the javascript callback?

I cannot seem to find any documentation regarding raw_id_field javascript callbacks, it seems very unlikely there aren't any hooks, what am I missing?